# Browser filters in SASS

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, sass

I'm working on an RoR app that uses SASS, I've been developing it in Chrome and it's come time to work on cross-browser compatibility.  For the most part everything looks fine but there's some small styling issues I'd like to fix.  Normal CSS filters haven't worked and I don't think that mixins are the solution, I don't need any variables in this situation and I haven't been able to find much on it.  Any pointers or advice?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect which features are available or not in the client's browser. It will append several classes to the `<html>` tag of your page, such as `no-textshadow`or `boxshadow`. Those are classes you can use in your css, even your mixin, like this :

```
@mixin box-shadow($shadow)
{
     @include box-shadow($shadow);
     .no-boxshadow &
     {
         @include box-shadow(none);
     }
}
```

UA sniffing in general, or detecting browser, is not anymore considered good practice as it is not future-proof. Modernizr detect features on the spot, and so even if there are a lot of browsers out there that don't support feature X or Y and that you don't know about, you can still work around them.

If it's just padding or magin issues, little style things like that, I recommand you use a css reset or better, a [Normalizer](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) to put every browser on the same level, erasing browser specific styles regarding elements.